# In R How can I extract a parent child hierarchy from HTML without node id's

Tags: html, r, parsing, hierarchy

I have an HTML file exported from a system that includes entity hierarchies and the only way they can export it to us with the hierarchy is in HTML.

I am trying to extract the entity names, and use either the "margin-left:" values or the tree structure to tell me when the indent changes, either way I need to know when the parent level changes.

I've tried XML, XML2, RCurl and selectr to break this down into nodes but had no luck.

The file they can give us looks like this in a browser:
[image]

The HTML code they can give us looks like this:

```html
<HTML><TITLE>My Hierarchy Title</TITLE><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:white"><style type="text/css">
 thead {display:table-row-group;}
 tfoot {display:table-row-group;}
 </style>
<div style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<table cellspacing="0" style="" border="0">
<thead style="color:000000;background-color:FFFF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" border="1pt"></thead>
<tbody style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:center;" border="1pt"><img src="C:\Local\Temp\Icon1000.bmp"></div>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div>Top Level Value - Not Indented - I want to Read into R</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt"></tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:1cm;">
<table cellspacing="0" style="" border="0">
<thead style="color:000000;background-color:FFFF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" border="1pt"></thead>
<tbody style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:center;" border="1pt"><img src="C:\Local\Temp\Icon1001.bmp"></div>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div>First Indented Value - 1 cm Indent - Parented by Top Level Value I want to read into R</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt"></tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:1cm;">
<table cellspacing="0" style="" border="0">
<thead style="color:000000;background-color:FFFF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" border="1pt"></thead>
<tbody style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:center;" border="1pt"><img src="C:\Local\Temp\Icon1002.bmp"></div>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div>Second Indented value also - 1 cm Indent - Parented by Top Level Value also to read into R</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt"></tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:2cm;">
<table cellspacing="0" style="" border="0">
<thead style="color:000000;background-color:FFFF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" border="1pt"></thead>
<tbody style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:center;" border="1pt"><img src="C:\Local\Temp\Icon1003.bmp"></div>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div>Third Value - 2 cm Indent - Parented by Second Indented Value seen above</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt"></tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:3cm;">
<table cellspacing="0" style="" border="0">
<thead style="color:000000;background-color:FFFF00;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" border="1pt"></thead>
<tbody style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt">
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div style="color:000000;background-color:FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:center;" border="1pt"><img src="C:\Local\Temp\Icon1004.bmp"></div>
</td>
<td style="padding:20px">
<div>Fourth Value - 3 cm Indent - Parented by Third Value</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot style="color:000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:10;text-align:left;" border="1pt"></tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:7cm;">
</BODY></HTML>
```

My sample code so far looks like this:

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
library(selectr)

ml <- read_html("~/R/Management Lines/rusample.htm")
ml.ls <- as_list(ml)
# list of length 2 returned - discard 1st list - keep second
ml.ls <- ml.ls[[2]]

# extract management line names from list object
divs <- seq(from=2, to=11, by=2)
for(i in 1:length(divs)){
  print(ml.ls[[divs[i]]][[2]][[2]]$tr[[3]]$div[[1]])
}
```

And it returns these ok - but I can't figure out how to extract the indents and cbind them with these results to get indent levels associated with these names:

```
> divs <- seq(from=2, to=11, by=2)
> for(i in 1:length(divs)){
+   print(ml.ls[[divs[i]]][[2]][[2]]$tr[[3]]$div[[1]])
+ }
[1] "Top Level Value - Not Indented - I want to Read into R"
[1] "First Indented Value - 1 cm Indent - Parented by Top Level Value I want to read into R"
[1] "Second Indented value also - 1 cm Indent - Parented by Top Level Value also to read into R"
[1] "Third Value - 2 cm Indent - Parented by Second Indented Value seen above"
[1] "Fourth Value - 3 cm Indent - Parented by Third Value"
>
```

Help!  This is driving me crazy because I know this can't be that hard.

Comment: What language is this? Whatever it is, mention it in your title and add a tag.

Comment: Sorry - edited question and tags to include this is in R.